# demonstrate tracking some bitcoin transactions with a program like an explorer

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, public-key, blockexplorer

Recently I started to read BITCOIN protocol and it's events when a transaction created. I want to create a program a bitcoin explorer.

as you know probably, Each non-coinbase input spends an outpoint from a previous transaction. and every input contains previous_output, script bytes, signature script and sequence. and a signature script is a script-language script which satisfies the conditions placed in the outpoint’s pubkey script.

my main question is how I can relate an output address with input which is show an UTXO. I want demonstrate tracking some transactions.